# Parser included whitespace when detecting a link

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255780/how-do-you-prove-this-algorithm-is-optimal) I posted a comment saying the question belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

I put the word "Also" next to the bare url, separated by a whitespace, but later when I looked at the comment it appears the "Also" became part of the link.

Comment: I'd have used `[codereview.se]` in comments for [codereview.se]

Comment: Can you copy-paste the raw body of the comment here for posterity?

Comment: Just testing the bug http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ lalala

Comment: option-space http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Also

Comment: @JoshCaswell Apparently when the bug gets fixed it gets fixed, so posterity is not served. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You inserted a non-breaking space, not a normal space, which confused the parser. I'm not sure that there's a legitimate reason to allow non-breaking spaces in raw URLs though, so the behaviour is likely still buggy.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how I did that.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time a mysterious non-breaking space showed up. Assuming you didn't copy and paste from elsewhere, I'd maybe blame some obscure browser condition.

Comment: @kojiro Some OS's (e.g., Mac OSX) allow you to insert a non-breaking space with [option]-[space], a relatively easy typo.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed and will be deployed in the next build.